# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar float y usar inline-block?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Me ha surgido la duda a partir de una maquetación que estoy haciendo y no sé cuál es la diferencia entre usar `float` o `inline-block`.

Si uso `inline-block` entre dos elementos, al segundo elemento siempre le queda un espacio arriba, tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si uso `float`, evito ese problema, pero los elementos se colocan a su antojo si redimensiono la página.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ambos?

¿Y cómo puedo evitar que se genere un espacio encima del segundo elemento al usar `inline-block`?

Comment: Consejo: No uses floats, aprende Flexbox y grid. Si dejas el código de lo que estás haciendo o imágenes de lo que quieres lograr te puedo hacer un ejemplo con ambos estilos de maquetación.

Comment: @AndySamuel gracias por el consejo. Estoy aprendiendo a usar flexbox, pero me ha surgido la duda esa porque lo he usado bastantes veces sin saber la diferencia.

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Float literalmente ignora los elementos que estén en medio y envía el elemento al float indicado, si este es left o right y el Inline Block como su nombre normalmente es con los nodos que son hijos

Comment: @Padron es decir, inline-block crea un elemento en línea pero respeta el espacio del resto de elementos, y float se impone por encima de elementos que no sean flotantes, ¿sería esa la explicación?

Comment: @unanobot Precisamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las diferencias son las siguientes:

float (left o right): Apila los elementos a la derecha o a la izquierda, pero como fue creado para poner texto alrededor de una imágen no es conveniente usarlo. Se pierde control del comportamiento del elemento, afectando posiblemente a otros elementos posteriores que quieras agregar.

inline-block: Te permite alinear los elementos uno al lado del otro, teniendo mayor control del comportamiento y es más amigable para los navegadores (No funciona en IE7 y versiones anteriores).

Te recomendaría utilizar display:flex e investigar sobre él. Te permite tener mayor control de los elementos y los nuevos navegadores ya están familiarizados con esta propiedad. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
.container {
  display: flex;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Float hace que puedas apilar los elementos en horizontal pero perderás control para poner un elemento en medio, inline-block también hace que apiles elementos en horizontal pero mantendrá uno en el medio y respetará el width del contenedor padre.

Aún así te recomiendo que no uses demasiado estas opciones y como te ha dicho más gente y aprende a usar adecuadamente Flex que te soluciona mucho la vida.